# Firebase dynamic link not creating in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am unable to create short dynamic link URL in my Android App.

**Exception:**

> com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 403: Requests to this
>   API firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com method
>   google.firebase.dynamiclinks.v1.DynamicLinksService.CreateShortDynamicLink
>   are blocked.

**Code:**

```
 fun buildDeepLink(deepLink: Uri, minVersion: Int): Task<ShortDynamicLink> {
                val uri =
                "https://name.page.link/" + Constant.DEEP_LINK_CODE.property_id + property!!.getid
                val uriPrefix = "https://name.page.link"

                val builder = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
                    .createDynamicLink()
                    .setDomainUriPrefix(uriPrefix)

                    .setAndroidParameters(
                        DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder()
                            .setMinimumVersion(minVersion)
                            .build()
                    )
                    .setLink(Uri.parse(uri))


                // Build the dynamic link
                val link = builder.buildShortDynamicLink()
                return link
            }
```

> note: "uriPrefix" is registered in firebase console.

Comment: If the SDK is giving you error messages that are not actionable, contact Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I got the same problem. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. You may need to register the SHA1 fingerprint in Firebase Console
If you are running in a debug build, you will need to register the SHA1 fingerprint of the debug key

Comment: issue got resolved after few days. do not know what was wrong.